# Azure Devops - Domain name is invalid

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create a virtual machine using ARM template. 
I  have added ARM template in my visual studio and have checked-in into the Azure Repos.
On running release pipeline I am receiving below error:

> InvalidDomainNameLabel: The domain name label $(dns) is invalid. It must conform to the following regular expression: ^[a-z][a-z0-9-]{1,61}[a-z0-9]$. []

Below is the parameter.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "adminUsername": {
      "value": "Myadmin"
    },
    "dnsNameForPublicIP": {
      "value": "mynewdevvmbox003"
    }
  }
}
```

dns name "mynewdevvmbox003" is matching the regular expression requirement but still, I am getting this error.

Comment: Just wanted to check in what the status on this issue was? Is it succeed for you to apply the ARM template now?

Answer (score 1):

> InvalidDomainNameLabel: The domain name label $(dns) is invalid.

According to this error message, the value of domain name that this task server got is `$(dns)`, not `mynewdevvmbox003`.

I think you should specified the override parameter value in **Override template parameters** of `Azure resource group deployment` task, such as `-dnsNameForPublicIP $(dns)`.

[image]

If you indeed specify like this, the value in parameter.json will not be parsed any more. Because the override content has **higher priority** than parameter.json. Here, `dns` is a pipeline varibale.

---

Please ensure select the `parameter.json` file in **Template parameters**:

[image]

And, do not specify `adminUsername` and `dnsNameForPublicIP` again in **Override template parameters** of the task.